# getattribute in OSL is not giving expected results

Tags: maya

I'm working on a custom OSL shader for Maya. I'm adding attributes to the shape node of objects and using getattribute() in my OSL code to manipulate those attributes. I have attributes for color correct, base color, rim width and rim color. (the last 2 are for facing ratio). My OSL always compiles and I'm always able to connect it to the material I'm using. But every time I check if it's working in the Arnold render view, my sliders on my attributes don't do anything. The goal is to have an image file connected to the base color of the material and have the color correct node affect base color (which would affect the texture file)

At first I thought my problem was I was trying to do too much in a single OSL node (I was using getattribute for all of the attributes I listed above). So I tried isolating it to just the color correct attribute and still nothing. Is anyone familiar with OSL and can help me?

This is what my OSL code is for color correct:

```
shader
colorCorrect
(
    float modifier = 1[[float min = 0, float max = 72]],
    color bob = 0,
    output color result = 0
)

{
    
    color temp = transformc("rgb", "hsv", bob);
    temp[0] = temp[0] * modifier;
    result = transformc("hsv", "rgb", temp);
}
```

This is what my OSL code is for facing ratio:

```
shader
Velvet(
    float rim_width = 0.2
        [[
        string label = "Rim Width",
        ]],
    color basecolor = color(1,1,1)
        [[
        string label = "Base Color",
        string widget = "checkBox",
        ]],
    color rimcolor = color(1,0,0)
        [[
        string label = "Rim Color",
        ]],
    output color resultRGB = 0,
    output float resultF = 0)

{
vector i = normalize(I);
vector n = normalize(N);
float  d = fabs(dot(-i, n));
d = smoothstep(rim_width, 1.0, d);
getattribute("base_color", resultRGB = mix(rimcolor, basecolor, d));
getattribute("rim_width", resultF = d - 0.5);
}
```

Comment: Do you get any output at all? I tested mutlitple outputs and as soon as I add a second output to the shader, the translator failes to connect and says there are incompatible types. With one single output float or color everything works. Arnold should be able to create multiple outputs and I was able to do it before but now it doesnt work any more.

Comment: I've only been getting 1 output. So originally, that one output would be for color correct, base color, rim color and rim width. But that wasn't working so I've tried isolating my OSL code to just do color correct.

Comment: Your colorCorrect node works fine for me even if I renamed it because maya already has a colorCorrect node.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The idea was to not have to use the color correct node in maya. I was making my own because I wanted to include a rim color and rim width.

Comment: Yes, but naming nodes the same way as in maya can lead to problems. So I renamed your shader to `cc` and it works fine for me.

Comment: I don't think that's the problem. I named my osl node "aiOslColorCorrect." When you ran the code, what material did you use? I am using aiToon. Could that be the problem? I was hoping it would work with that material for a larger project.

Comment: I used a aiLambert for testing.

Comment: Do you use an inline shader with an aiOSLShader node? If so then multiple outputs do not work with inline shaders. If you create an external shader this should work. Concerning your color correct shader. Does it work on your side?